# changing the objects in an array but not the number of objects - c++

Tags: c++, segmentation-fault

I'm struggling with a segmentation fault somewhere in my program and I think it might be in this snippet of code.  `ingredients` is a pointer to an array of `Ingredient` objects.  Now, the overloaded * operator just changes each of the Ingredient objects in the array.  So, it seems to me that I'm just changing the objects that the pointer is pointing to but I'm not changing the size of the array i.e. I'm not attempting to add more objects to the `Ingredient` array.  Do I, for some reason, still need to deallocate memory?

```
Recipe Recipe::operator*(const Fraction multiplier)
{
    for (int count = 0; count < numIngredients; count++)
    {
        ingredients[count] * multiplier;
    }
    servings = multiplier;
    return *this;
}
```

Comment: *Please* don't do this. If you're doing to modify the destination object, you should be overloading something like `operator*=` to at least give a reasonable warning of the modification. As for your question about deallocation: I don't think you've told us enough to make a reasonable guess at it.

Comment: What does this `ingredients[count] * multiplier;` do?

Comment: Shouldn't `ingredients[count] * multiplier;` result in **no operation** ?

Comment: Segfault usually means uninitialized pointers.  Show us the constructor, and how you add ingredients.

Comment: Deallocating memory will never (in any circumstance that I can think of, anyway) fix a segmentation fault; it just prevents memory leaks.

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, a few comments.

Your `Recipe::operator*` is not `const` when it should be, and modifies itself.

This is like doing:

```
a = 5
b = a * 2
```

And having `a = 10` at the end of this.

That's conceptually wrong.

What you've done is defined `Recipe::operator*=`

You should define `Recipe::operator*=` and `Recipe::operator*` like the following:

```
Recipe& Recipe::operator*=(const Fraction multiplier)
{
    for (int count = 0; count < numIngredients; count++)
    {
        ingredients[count] * multiplier;
    }
    servings = multiplier;
    return *this;
}

Recipe Recipe::operator*(const Fraction multiplier)
{
    Recipe x = *this;
    x *= multiplier;
    return x;
}
```

Regarding the segfault, we'd need to see all the code to see what is happening there. It could be anywhere in your program, but things to look at would be your copy constructor for example.

Answer (score 0):

I don't see anything in that code that would necessarily cause a crash, but a problem somewhere else could cause it to crash there.  For example, if the numIngredients member wasn't correct, or the ingredients pointer was null.  It is odd that operator* is being used for the ingredients.  Normally the binary operator * would return a value and not modify the arguments, but the return value isn't being used.  Ingredient::operator* could be defined to modify the ingredient in some way, it would just be unusual.  You would probably have to give more code for the problem to become clear.

Answer (score 0):

Check the value of `numIngredients`. It may be wrong.